# Help writing Dirichlet (multidimensional Beta) PDF correctly

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, bayesian

I am not getting a PDF when I attempt to express the Dirichlet distribution over the random variable vector $\mathbf{\theta}=(\theta_1, ..., \theta_{27})$. Suppose a total of $2000$ observations on the random variable vector $\mathbf{X} = (x_1, x_2, ... x_{27})$.  Suppose $x_{5}$ "e" appears $260$ times over the $2000$ observations. Assume the remaining $(2000-260)=2340$ observations are identically distributed over the other $\mathbf{X} - \{x_5\}$ random variables, which gives me $(2000-2600)/26 = 90$ observations for each $x_i$ in $\mathbf{X}$ for $i \ne 5$.  This gives me a Dirichlet distribution over $\mathbf{\theta}$ with parameter $\mathbf{X}$. My probability density function is

$$ =\int_{0}^1 \frac{\Gamma(2600)}{\Gamma(260)\Gamma(90)^{26}} \theta_{5}^{260-1}\theta_1^{90-1}\theta_2^{90-1}...\theta_{26}^{90-1}  \mathrm d\theta  $$

Since I do not know how to integrate over the vector $\theta$ (is this a simple computation?), I wanted to try to rewrite the PDF in terms of the scalar $\theta_5$. Doing so gives me

$$ =\int_{0}^1 \frac{\Gamma(2600)}{\Gamma(260)\Gamma(90)^{26}} \theta_{5}^{260-1}((\small{\frac{1}{26}})(1 -\theta_5)^{90-1})^{26}  \mathrm d\theta  $$

but I seem to have a mistake in this somewhere since [evaluating the integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20%28%20Gamma%282600%29%20/%20%28Gamma%28260%29%28Gamma%2890%29%5E26%29%29%29%28%CE%B8%5E%28260-1%29%29%28%28%281-%CE%B8%29/%2826%29%29%5E%28%2889%29%2a26%29%29d%CE%B8,%20%CE%B8=0..1) does not equal $1$.

Can someone please help me correct this Dirichlet distribution over $\mathbf{\theta}$ with parameter $\mathbf{X}$? A solution that works in the general case of a parameter vector $\mathbf{X}$ (i.e. does not assume Beta distribution) would be appreciated.

Comment: $(2000-260)=2340$ and $(2000-2600)/26=90$? Really? :-) For the integral, you should actually have 27 integrals. If $\Theta$ denotes the parameter space for the vector, then $\int_\Theta=\int_0^1\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1$ - 27 of them. But you can move them around so you get $\propto \int_0^1\theta_1^{x_1-1}d\theta_1\int_0^1\theta_2^{x_2-1}d\theta_2\cdots\int_0^1\theta_{27}^{x_{27}-1}d\theta_{27}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To express the Dirichlet (multivariate generalization of Beta) properly, make sure that $1- \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \alpha_i = \alpha_k$, and $\sum_{j=1}^k \theta_j = 1$, and that the it is a distribution over a $(k-1)$ dimensional space. So there would be $(k-1)$ independent parameters. [See this example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?_=1375847803136&i=Int%203027024000%20%20%2ax%5E%283-1%29%20%2a%20%28y%5E%284-1%29%20%29%20%2a%20%28z%5E%285-1%29%29%2a%28%20%28%201-%28x%2by%2bz%29%20%29%5E%285-1%29%20%29%20dz%20dy%20dx,%20for%20x%20=%200..1,%20y%20=%200..%281-x%29,%20z=0..%281-%28x%2by%29%29&fp=1&incTime=true). If you have a conditional probability of only $2$ parameters but need to have a Dirichlet distribution over $27$, then you would substitute an expression in terms of the $2$ parameters you do have for the other $25$.  Of course make sure the integral  over $0$ to $1$ equals $1$.